# Хор, хорошо, хоронить - являются ли эти слова родственниками?

Tags: этимология, проверочные-слова

**Хор**, **хорошо**, **хоронить** - являются ли эти слова родственниками? Можно ли **хором** проверить первое **о** в х**о**ронить и х**о**рошо? Так же интересно было бы узнать и о происхождении данных слов.

Answer (score 1):

Если хор - это группа поющих, то точно нет. "Хор" от греческого "хорос" - "групповой танец". Хорошо - от хорошиться, храбриться. Хоронить от праславянского "хорна" - хранить, охрана, корм, пища.

Answer (score 0):

Оба от орать - пахать, а это не просто и с ором - криком на скотину. Именно оттуда арии.  Землепашцы. Вспахал - отдохнул,   поорал от радости, да не один, а с группой товарищей.
Поплясал с ором, хором. Потом опять пахать - урожай собирать и опять хором с ором. Не собрал - срам, потом храм (беда). Собрал - хором и в хоромы, чтоб не украли - кромы-закрома. 
Успел - попел, хором. А ош - медведь, если их много - то хор ош, а ежели не успел, то хором и в отдельные хоромы, а туда и припасы для Хор ган (курган).  Хорошего человека. Кагана.
Скифское золото. Интересно откуда на русской равнине золото.  Купили. За что?

Comment: А че не нравится? ош не медведь, и Oso  не медведь, и берлога--не медвежья? и кохать не-любить? И Коганы--не фамилия?